# DDeboer connect fail in imap gmail

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I need some help with lib DDeboer-Imap.
I'm having trouble connecting to a Gmail account, I've already made all the possible settings I found on the internet, including enabling imap on the account, enabling less secure apps, disabling any irregular activity, but none of this is working, I'm having the same feedback :

Error response:

```
 [ERROR] Error: [E_WARNING] Authentication failed for user "xxxxxxx@gmail.com":
         imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
         {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/validate-cert}
         imap_alerts (0):
         imap_errors (1):
         - Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your
         web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco
```

The php version is 7.2, all libs are active, imap, openssl, and others that I verified are necessary, and as said, nothing makes the account connect.

I have also tried to change to connect without SSL, but without success.

Below is the excerpt from my code.

```
try {
            foreach ($mailboxes as $key => $mailbox) {
                $hostname = 'custom' == $mailbox['server'] ? $mailbox['imap'] : $mailbox['server'];
                $cert = 143 == $mailbox['port'] ? '/imap/novalidate-cert' : '/imap/ssl/validate-cert';

                $server = new Server($hostname, $mailbox['port'], $cert);
                $connection = $server->authenticate($mailbox['email'], $mailbox['password']);

                $this->readMailboxes($connection, $mailbox);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), 1);
        }
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Max, the erros is in the print: https://prnt.sc/sfuyuz

Comment: Please copy and paste your error into the question so it is useful for searches.  We want questions and answers to be self contained.

Comment: added in post main.

Comment: Does your IMAP library support Google OAuth?  Without OAuth support, you're unlikely to log in to an account from a remote host without tripping their security measures.

Comment: The security issues in the account have already removed all of them.
Regarding the item "oAuth" in Imap, how do I check on the server if this configuration exists? At first I installed the standard imap library that PHP has.

Comment: Google will enforce security no matter how much try to turn it off.  It will generally prevent access from places that end users don't typically access email from (web hosts, cloud computing services, etc.), unless you are using OAuth2, that is what that "Please log in via your web browser" message means.  php-imap does not support the required security measures.  You will need a new IMAP library, or use Google libraries for other methods of access.  Have you considered their REST api?